# Show number of upvotes/downvotes of a question in search engine results?

Tags: feature-request, upvotes

Sometimes, there are duplicates or different versions of the same question all of which appear in the search results. Number of upvotes would help to determine the most relevant question for the first time itself.

I want this because, I mostly Google for what I know but don't remember clearly, and a quick glance would suffice to remember. And I have to Google every minute everytime I'm working on something. So, this feature would help spot the most relevant question quickly.

Regardless of my scenario, it would be helpful to have Stack Overflow SEO-optimize to show the votes in the search results itself.

Comment: And your request seems muddled; are you talking about the Google search results or the results shown by the internal search engine of the site itself?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Search engine results it is. Thanks!

Comment: Last but not least, the score breakdown of a post is an expensive database query per post, which is why you need to have reached the [established user privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) before you can use it. Giving this breakdown to everyone in search results would be technically unfeasible.

Comment: Also, Google already is given the question and answer *with score* marked up in a machine-readable standard format. It is up to **Google** to display the score, that is not something Stack Exchange can influence!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't have broad idea about SEO techniques but I read about creating certain type of HTML snippets would enable it to be shown in the search results.

Comment: Yes, the markup is *already there*. Google is just not using it (yet).

Comment: See [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233858) and [Does Google special-case for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136414) for some context.

Comment: That sounds fair now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Overflow *already* gives search engines everything they need to show the post score. It is up to the search engine to actually display this or not.

Stack Overflow question pages are marked up using the [Schema.org QAPage microformat](http://schema.org/QAPage), which tells search engines (and other interested parties) that the page is a question-and-answer page, what parts form the question, what parts are answers, how many answers there are in the page, and the score for each of these parts.

In the past Google already made use of this information to show the number of answers for questions when listing links to Stack Overflow results. It is entirely up to Google and other search engines to show the question score with results; Stack Overflow cannot *make* Google do this.

Also see:

- [Does Google special-case for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136397/does-google-special-case-for-stack-overflow/136414#136414)
- [Google "answering" my search with link to SE, but not showing the top answer(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233845/google-answering-my-search-with-link-to-se-but-not-showing-the-top-answers/233858#233858)

Comment: Google shows upvotes and Top answer now. :D